# How to find parent from child scope in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Not entirely sure how to word my need properly. Code reflects it better:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.know_your_parent
    p ? # <------- is it possible to get order.id here?
  end
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

(order=Account.new).assign_attributes({id: 4}, without_protection: true)
order.products.know_your_parent # => "4"
```

Comment: `order.products.first.try(:order_id)` will give you `nil` if no products, or the `order_id`

Comment: @apneadiving `self.know_your_parent` sees no class method `order`. it does see `first` however (and it works properly - retrieves first product of particular order), but it won`t work in case there isn't any product assigned to order.

Comment: it will work, that's the interest of `try`

Comment: @apneadiving it won't raise an exception, but will return nil. nil is not what I`m asking for.

Comment: see, maybe this would help: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association

Comment: @apneadiving even if there lies an answer, I`m not really able to figure it out :(

Answer (score 0):

In your example `order.products.know_your_parent`, know_your_parent function is called on the Array
So if you can extend the array adding the function, you should be able to do it. But I'm not sure it is recommended to extend and use it that way.